# From a stochastic process to the probability distribution of increments

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability

Let $X_t$ be a continuous stochastic process which is Hölder continuous for every $a<1/2$.

Let's also assume that we know the probability distribution of the process, i.e. if we fix $t_1>0$, then the random variable $X_{t_1}$ has a known probability density function $f_{t_1}$. We assume that $f_{t_1}$ is a smooth function for all $t_1>0$ and the mapping $t_1 \mapsto f_{t_1}$ is continuous.

If we fix $t_2>t_1>0$, what can we say about the probability distribution of $Y_{t_2,t_1} = X_{t_2} - X_{t_1}$? Is there a simple, closed form formula that gives its probability density function? Do we need any more assumptions to answer this question?

Comment: Note that continuity of $t \mapsto f_t$ cannot be anyhow helpful, because $t_2 > t_1 + \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon >0$ so that $f_{t_2}, f_{t_1}$ can have nothing in common. This question is then equivalent with asking about random variable $Z=X-Y$, when you know that both have smooth densities. Can you in general tell the distribution of $Z$, without any other assumption? We need to know about  "dependence" of each other

Comment: @DominikKutek the dependence is exactly what I don't know in this case. What I know is that the process is almost a Weiner, but I don't know how to quantify this "almost".